# Rails 4 - Parsing Stripe Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have the below Stripe script that retrieves some account info from Stripe. This is on a html.erb page.

```
  <%= 
      require "stripe" 
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"] 
      Stripe::Recipient.retrieve("rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6")
  %>
```

the output of the above in my html view is:

```
{ "id": "rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6", "object": "recipient", "created": 1415734250, "livemode": false, "type": "individual", "description": null, "email": null, "name": "Rob Smith", "verified": false, "metadata": {}, "active_account": {"id":"ba_14xkLj2Wc0ZCCMLmDrfCmjJH","object":"bank_account","last4":"6789","country":"US","currency":"usd","status":"new","fingerprint":"fsQXqyeIRbyqMsvW","bank_name":"BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.","default_for_currency":false,"disabled":false,"validated":false,"verified":false}, "cards": {"object":"list","total_count":0,"has_more":false,"url":"/v1/recipients/rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6/cards","data":[],"count":0}, "default_card": null }
```

From the above, I want to extract 4 columns: name, country, bank name, last4.

I've tried adding the variable name to the end like `Stripe::Recipient.retrieve("rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6").name` but I get errors saying the local variable name is not defined.

UPDATED CODE:

```
  <%= require "stripe" 
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"] 
      rp = Stripe::Recipient.retrieve("rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6")

      "Name: #{rp['name']}"
      "Bank Name: #{rp['bank_name']}"
      "Last 4 of Account Number: #{rp['last4']}"
  %>
```

When I only keep the name line above, it works. But when I add the bank name and last 4, the output is simply the text of the last line "Last 4 of Account Number"

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably elsewhere, since `Stripe::Recipient.retrieve` returns an instance of `Stripe::Recipient`, which does have a `name` attribute.

Unless you post a more detailed error message, I can't provide you a more detailed answer.

Comment: So `Stripe::Recipient.retrieve("rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6").name` should work?

Comment: It should yes. You can try it in a console. If it doesn't work you probably need to check the docs for the version of the gem you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
recipient = Stripe::Recipient.retrieve("rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6")
recipient['name']
```

Explanation: `Stripe::Recipient.retrieve` returns hash-like value, not object-like. So you have to call `hash[:attribute]` instead of `hash.attribute`

UPD: <%= %> will print only the last line. Try that:

```
<% require "stripe" 
  Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"] 
  rp = Stripe::Recipient.retrieve("rp_14xkLm12344CMLmVxUbW3A6")
%>
<%= "Name: #{rp['name']}" %>
<%= "Bank Name: #{rp['bank_name']}" %>
<%= "Last 4 of Account Number: #{rp['last4']}" %>
```

Or use a helper.

UPD2:
Do you really need a `require 'stripe'` call? I've used stripe gem, but don't remember I needed that  at all. And setting Stripe.api_key should belong to initializer, not to view.

Comment: And actually placing Ruby code inside HTML is a bad practice. Try to move stripe require and recipient fetching code to controller or even a service to make it cleaner.

Comment: i updated your answer. Bank and account info were in different objects so I had to call them differently. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Since this is in a html file, I'm not sure where to place the require code? It is a user specific view so should I place this in the user controller up at the top?

Comment: Rejected. You wanted to put `rp.name` instead of `rp['name']` back, and that will break your code.

Comment: It works though. Will it cause problems in certain situations? I changed it because I wasn't sure how to use the second object call in the bank columns. I tried it with the . and it worked.

Comment: Your initial question was why `rp.name` doesn't work. I've shown you what's wrong with that and explained you should use `rp['name']. Then you have done another fixes. Now you want to do something else, which possibly will break it once more for someone.